# 2's complement converter in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting stuck and I've been looking at my code for hours and I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. What my function does is that it will take in either a negative or positive number and convert it into its 32-bit 2’s complement hexadecimal representations. My function takes in an array of characters (in 32 bit signed magnitude representation) and take the 2's complement of the array. My approach to converting it to 2's complement is simply assign a character into the array when a certain character is seen. Special case occurs if the character seen in the array is the first one. The rest is normally negated. I'm currently stuck. When I enter the value -23 (signed magnitude is 80000017) I get the value K00000KK. -23452 (signed magnitude 80005B9C) --> K000KKKK. I set the value to be 'K' to find out where the code was getting stuck at, the original value was '7'. In the code, I put display messages to see where the compiler is going

```
for -23 (80000017) input I get the messages

first 1 is seen, leave first 1 the same
first 1 is seen, leave first 1 the same
no one's showed up yet --> 0
no one's showed up yet --> 0
no one's showed up yet --> 0
no one's showed up yet --> 0
no one's showed up yet --> 0
first 1 is seen, leave first 1 the same
```

Pretty much where K is shown is where i get the first 1 message and where 0 is shown i get the --> 0 message

Thank you for your help! much appreciated!

Here is a pastebin link to my code because the formatting of the code annoyed me...

http://pastebin.com/KSeymwcs

```
char* two_complement(int number, char* sign_mag_array){

int first_one_flag = 0;

if(number > 0){
    cout << "positive number" << endl;
    return sign_mag_array;
}

if(number < 0){
    for(int q = 7; q >= 0; q--){
        if(first_one_flag == 1){                // negate the rest regularly
            cout << "negate normally " << endl;

            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '0'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'F';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '1'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'E';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '2'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'D';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '3'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'C';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '4'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'D';
            }   
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '5'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'A';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] = '6'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '9';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '7'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '8';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '8'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '7';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] = '9'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '6';
            }   
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'A'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '5';
            }   
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'B'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '4';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] = 'C'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '3';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'D'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '2';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'E'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '1';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'F'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '0';
            }
        }


        if(sign_mag_array[q] == '0' && first_one_flag == 0){
            cout << "no one's showed up yet --> 0 " << endl;
        }
        else{                                               // first '1' in binary seen. special negating
            //first_one_flag = 1;               
            cout << "first 1 is seen, leave first 1 the same " << endl;

            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '1'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'F';        
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '2'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'E';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '3'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'D';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '4'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'C';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '5'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'B';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '6'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'A';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] = '7'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '9';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '8'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '8';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == '9'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = 'K';
            }       
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'A'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '6';
            }   
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'B'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '5';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'C'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '4';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'D'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '3';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'E'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '2';
            }
            if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'F'){
                sign_mag_array[q] = '1';
            }
        }
    }    
}
return sign_mag_array;
```

}

Comment: Enable warnings on your compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errors are simple

```
        if(sign_mag_array[q] = '7'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '9';
        }
```

should be

```
        if(sign_mag_array[q] == '7'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '9';
        }
```

and

```
        if(sign_mag_array[q] = 'C'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '3';
        }
```

should be

```
        if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'C'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '3';
        }
```

and

```
        if(sign_mag_array[q] = '9'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '6';
        }
```

should be

```
        if(sign_mag_array[q] == '9'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '6';
        }
```

etc. etc. I think you get the idea,

Code with this much repetition is bad style and makes errors like this easy to make. You should be able to greatly simplify and shorten this code with a little bit of mathematics.

For instance add two functions to convert hex digits to integers and vice versa

```
int hex_to_int(char x)
{
   return x <= '9' ? x - '0' : 10 + (x - 'A');
}

char int_to_hex(int x)
{
   return x < 10 ? '0' + x : 'A' + (x - 10);
}
```

and now code like this

```
       if(sign_mag_array[q] == '0'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = 'F';
        }
        if(sign_mag_array[q] == '1'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = 'E';
        }
        ...
        if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'E'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '1';
        }
        if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'F'){
            sign_mag_array[q] = '0';
        }
```

becomes

```
     if (sign_mag_array[q] >= '0' && sign_mag_array[q] <= '9' || 
         sign_mag_array[q] >= 'A' && sign_mag_array[q] <= 'F')
     {
         int digit = hex_to_int(sign_mag_array[q]);
         sign_mag_array[q] = int_to_hex(15 - digit);
     }
```

That's 48 lines of repetitious code reduced to very little. And as a bonus it also fixes the problem that Zeta spotted.

Comment: I like your function john! but every element in my array. I don't think I can have an array will multiple types. I'm trying to find a way to edit your functions so it will only deal with char.

Comment: @Liondancer Sorry there was an error in my code. I wrote `15 - int_to_hex(digit);` when I meant `int_to_hex(15 - digit);` I've fixed it now, see above. It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what [john](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16029911/1139697) said, your logic is currently wrong. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
    if(sign_mag_array[q] == '1'){
        sign_mag_array[q] = 'F';        
    }
    /* ... */
    if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'F'){
        sign_mag_array[q] = '1';
    }
```

If `sign_mag_array[q]`  is `'1'` you will set it to `'F'`. This will result in the later condition being true and thus `sign_mag_array[q]` being reset to `'1'`.

You want *exclusive* conditions:

```
    if(sign_mag_array[q] == '1'){
        sign_mag_array[q] = 'F';        
    }
    else if(sign_mag_array[q] == '2'){
        sign_mag_array[q] = 'E';        
    }
    /* ... */
    else if(sign_mag_array[q] == 'F'){
        sign_mag_array[q] = '1';
    }
```

And since your already going exclusive you could simply use a `switch` instead of a long sequence of ifs:

```
switch(sign_mag_array[q]){
    case 'F': sign_mag_array[q] = '1'; break;
    case 'E': sign_mag_array[q] = '2'; break;
    /* ... */
    case '1': sign_mag_array[q] = 'F'; break;
}
```